# Nuxt project throws CSRF token mismatch 419 error while trying to login users through Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

**Structure of the project:**

2 folders namely `api` and `client`, where api is used for laravel installation and client refers to the nuxt project.

**Laravel (v-8.00) setups:**

This is what I have in `.env` file for the session variables

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:3000
```

`cors.php` contains the following

```
'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    'login',
    'logout',
    'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => false,

'max_age' => true,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

No changes made to `sanctum.php` and it contains

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1')),
```

**Nuxt Setups**

`.env` file contains:

```
PORT=3000
HOST=127.0.0.1
BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:3000
API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

`nuxt.config.js` contains:

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
],
/*
** Axios module configuration
** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
*/
axios: {
    baseUrl: process.env.API_URL,
    credentials: true,
},

auth: {
    strategies: {
    cookie: {
        cookie: {
        name: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        }
    },
        'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: process.env.API_URL
        },
    },
    redirect: {
        login: '/login',
        logout: '/login',
        callback: '/login',
        home: '/'
    }
},
```

`Login.vue` has

```
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                email: '',
                password: ''
            },
            errors: {}
        }
    },

    methods: {
        async submit () {
            this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', { data: this.form })
            .then(response => {
                this.$router.push(`/`)
            })
            .catch(({response}) => {
                this.errors = response.data.errors
            })

        }
    },
```

**Responses**

This is what I am getting in response when trying to log a user in:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the Request Headers for your login request please?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question. But I just ran into this myself and thought I'd share what worked for me.

Apparently, setting `SESSION_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1` throws a `419` error with "CSRF token mismatch".

However, if you set it to **`SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost`**, it works just fine.

Comment: I don't know why, but this worked for me as well.
Everything works for Firefox, but with Chrome it's not saving & sending the XSRF-TOKEN cookie with every request. After changing `.localhost` to `localhost` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

419 error means that your session domain is not correctly set.
If you are using localhost set your domain *like* below

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
```

Remove . before localhost

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```